# Cash app Bitcoin transaction stuck on the blockchain for over 2 months. What should I do?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, cash-app

Yes I had a withdrawal from wild.io casino sent to my cash app where it was rejected and reversed with a 42-cent fee it has now been 2 months and 4 days since it was reversed!! I have went as far as paying a couple people and a site to get my Bitcoin transaction unstuck and was very unsuccessful and just got my money taken!! I am fairly new to all this cryptocurrency stuff and cash app won't give me nothing no information on what to do and wild.io can't do nothing about it either!! Can somebody please give me some insight on what to do if I have any options!! Somebody please help me out with this I really could use the money right now in the worst possible way!!